# I can't debug the simple codes in Visual Studio Code using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am trying to debug this very simple code, but it doesn't do anything after I input a number.

```
import math

pi = math.pi

r = int(input('Enter number:'))

circum = 2 * pi * r
print(circum)
```

But for the simple and complicated codes which don't contain `input()`, I can debug them very easily. When I debug this code in Spyder, it does perfectly, but not in Visual Studio Code. I really need help

PS. I have already configured launch.json

Comment: What the output in console do you see? Nothing?

Comment: After I insert a number, this code should show the result of variable 'circum'. In Visual Studio Code, it doesn't show anything after that and still keep debugging.

Comment: Check, maybe you saw to some another window, check the output in `OUTPUT` tab int `TERMINAL` and so on

Comment: I have done everything you say. I have checked every window. There are 4 windows, Problem, Output, Debug and Terminal. There is no result after I insert a number. The result should be in debug window. But there are just 'Enter number:' and my inserted number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work when i switched to use the "Integrated Terminal/Console" debug configuration.

```
{
        "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit"
        ]
    },
```

[image]

[image]

https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/debugging_terminal-console-apps/#Option-1

Comment: One thing to note, my Python version is 2.7.  This should still work for 3.+ though.  The regular Python configuration doesn't accept user input which is why the program would freeze even in the Debug console.  When I switched to the "Integrated Terminal/Console" then the console allowed the user to accept input.